# Selenium: how to define css if webpage has mutiple elements with same name

Tags: css, selenium

I have the following HTML code:

```
<table id="userPlaylistTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<div class="numCellWrapper">
<div class="listArrow up" onclick="moveRowUp($(this))"></div>
<div class="numCell"> 1 </div>
<div class="listArrow down" onclick="moveRowDown($(this))"></div>
</div>
<div class="numCellWrapper">
<div class="listArrow up" onclick="moveRowUp($(this))"></div>
<div class="numCell"> 2 </div>
<div class="listArrow down" onclick="moveRowDown($(this))"></div>
</div>
<div class="numCellWrapper">
<div class="listArrow up" onclick="moveRowUp($(this))"></div>
<div class="numCell"> 3 </div>
<div class="listArrow down" onclick="moveRowDown($(this))"></div>
</div>
```

Basically, now if I define my css as:

```
css=table#userPlaylistTable div[class='listArrow up']
```

It picks the first such element it finds. But, how would I have to define my css, so that it picks second element of this type?
So, basically how would I define my css to pick a particular element, if multiple elements of the same kind exist on the page?

Could someone please help me with this query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like:

```
css=table#userPlaylistTable>div[class='listArrow up']:nth(1)

css=table#userPlaylistTable>div[class='listArrow up']:nth(2)
```

This will give you the 2nd and the 3rd instance

Comment: Hi Varun, this does not seem to be working. I am working on python and i tried the following: click("css=table#userPlaylistTable div[class='listArrow up']:nth({0})".format(num)). where num can be set to 1 or 2. do you see anything wrong here, which i cant?

Comment: ok it worked, my bad, there was some other problem..thanks for the help

Comment: "Houston, we have a problem!" Umm, I am really wondering how this could have worked because there is no `:nth()` pseudo-class in CSS--I assume `:nth-child()` is what was meant, right?

Answer (score 0):

add [1] which is the index into the array. usually 0 based, so [1] is the second element

Comment: So u mean something like this? css=table#userPlaylistTable div[class='listArrow up'][1]

Comment: actually I found that [1] was the first element and [2] the second.

Answer (score 0):

css: #userPlaylistTable .listArrow.up:nth-of-type[2]

Instead of [2] replace with item you want to select

**Description:**

id is # -- #userPlaylistTable

class by . listArrow up, but we have space between class name so replace space with . -- .listArrow.up

:nth-of-type(n) will select child